# Component view ngClass not updating

Tags: angular, state, ngrx-store

I am currently in the middle of incorporating @ngrx state management package into an already existing Angular2 application. So far everything has been going swimmingly but I am having an issue where an [ngClass] directive is not working correctly when returning to a previous component and maintaining state via the app store.

The funcitonality that I am attempting to implement is when a user clicks on a category, that link gets given a css class 'active' using a property on the component class called 'selectedCategory' which is updated in the @ngrx store. When a user clicks on an individual product it take them away to a seperate product component. Then, when a user returns to the original component the link should be given the class 'active' again as the 'selectedCategory' was stored in the @ngrx store. This isn't working though and it seems as if my [ngClass] directive isn't working as it should.

Here is my code (please note this is all being refactored as we speak so ignore anything you may think looks odd).

category-tree component

```
@Component({
    selector: 'category-tree',
    templateUrl: './app/views/directives/category-tree-view.html'
})

export class CategoryTree {
    @Input() categories: Category[];
    @Output() categoryChange:EventEmitter<any>;
    contentLoaded = false;
    selectedCategory: Category;
    categoriesLower = [];
    APIError = [];

    constructor(
        private _categoryService: CategoryService,
        private _store: Store<ProductViewerStore>
    ) {
        this.categoryChange = new EventEmitter();

        _store.select('selectedCategory')
            .subscribe((selectedCategory) => {
                this.selectedCategory = selectedCategory;
            });
    }

    categoryClick(category) {
        this._store.dispatch({ type: 'MAKE_CATEGORY_SELECTED', payload: category });
        this.getCategoriesLower(category);
    }
```

And it's view:

```
<li *ngFor="let category of categories" class='desktop-menu'>
    <span (click)="categoryClick(category)" [ngClass]="{'selected' : category === selectedCategory}">{{category.name}}</span>
    <ul *ngIf="category.sub_categories"  class='sub-category'>
        <category-tree [categories]="category.sub_categories"></category-tree>
    </ul>
</li>
```

And the selectedCategory @ngrx reducer:

```
import {Category} from "../../classes/Category";

export const selectedCategory = (state: Category, action) => {
    switch(action.type) {
        case 'MAKE_CATEGORY_SELECTED':
            return action.payload;
        case 'RESET_SELECTED_CATEGORY':
            return {};
        default:
            return state;
    }
};
```

As you can see in my component code, the selectedCategory component is being stored and being returned correctly in the subscription.. it just seems as if my view template ngClass is not running when this Observable has returned and resolved. Can anyone see the problem here?

Thanks

Comment: very interesting problem. can you create plunker.

Answer (score 0):

If `selectedCatagory` is an `Object`, perhaps your `===`, which does a reference check, is not resolving correctly?  It *looks* okay, but perhaps something is happening with ngrx in that regard?